# Img class with image bg remove border

Tags: html, css

I have a img class with a background image and I has a unusual gray border on it making a box. I want to remove the border but having a border:0px doesn't solve the problem.

I Provided a fiddle to replicate my work. Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhsqcz1/)

```css
.facebook {
  background: url(http://dev.truewarpit.com/play/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress-master/img/icons/facebook.png);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="facebook" alt="Facebook Logo" />
```

Comment: any reason why you are using `background-image` for `<img>`

Comment: transition effect on hover is not working on my previous setup. I need to think of some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the default border that appears when you use an img element with an a src attribute set to something that doesn't exist or doesn't has a src. Just use src attribute:

```css
.facebook {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.facebook:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
```

```html
<img class="facebook" alt="Facebook Logo" src="http://dev.truewarpit.com/play/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress-master/img/icons/facebook.png" />
```

Comment: is it possible to add some transition effect like fade in fade out to that because that the main problem I switch to this setup.

Comment: On hover for example?

Comment: Yup on hover. From .5 to 1 opacity with transition. But the only thing that work is the opacity, the transition codes are ignored.